# Is $23$ the only number which is not the sum of $2$ squares and $2$ non-negative cubes?

Tags: number-theory

Is $23$ the only number which is not the sum of $2$ squares and $2$ non-negative cubes?
I have checked up to $n=1,000,000,000$ and $n=23$ is the only number for which
$n=i^2+j^2+k^3+l^3$ has no solution where $i \ge 0, j \ge 0, k \ge 0$ and $l \ge 0$

Comment: This has been asked here. I will search - so far I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310142/is-there-any-number-pattern-in-the-sum-of-square-of-two-nos-and-cube-of-2-nos?noredirect=1), but it allows negative integers. Similarly, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174240/integers-of-the-form-a2b2c3d3?noredirect=1). Still, the answer by Will suggest that $23$ is the only one.

Comment: Your first statement says "positive", but later you ask for $i,j,k,l \ge 0$. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry I meant non-negative. Will correct the question.